# angular animations style, vscode, автоподсказки

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code, angular-animations

Начал знакомиться с `angular-animations`. Когда я описываю объект в `style({})` было бы очень удобно, если бы мне редактор vscode подсказывал значения как в css. Есть какое-то решение для этого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно есть какие-то экстеншны но не то что-бы я был в курсе. как вариант - кастомные снипеты.

Ctrl + Shift + P -> Configure User Snippets -> typescript

```
"Quick Log": {
    "prefix": "cl",
    "body": [
        "console.log($1)",
    ],
    "description": "Console Log"
},
```

По аналогии что-то типо

```
"Transition": {
    "prefix": "transition",
    "body": [
        " transition('$1 <=> $2', animate('$3'))",
    ],
    "description": "Transition"
},
```